# Does Ubuntu have kernel config requirements?

Tags: kernel, arm

I'm building a stripped-down variant of the kernel for an arm-based device and I want to use Ubuntu there. Does Ubuntu require some specific kernel options to be set? Also, is it necessary to apply Ubuntu's own patchset on top of the kernel (similar to https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.3.12/ for 5.3.12)?

I'm aware of https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel, but modifying existing config is harder than writing it based on default one (since Ubuntu tries to be universal and includes a lot of modules). It takes ages to build and just wastes the space (which is scarce).

Comment: The question is too broad. Ubuntu doesn't "require" any config. But it's config is a part of distribution.

Comment: There is no need to apply the Ubuntu patchset, and indeed the mainline kernels do not have it applied. The mainline kernels, by definition, must reflect the upstream current release candidate.

Comment: Did you notice that one of the selections available at the link you gave for mainline kernels is arm64 and another is armhf. I suspect that all the customization needed for arm devices is included.

Comment: @Pilot6: for other distributions there are requirements. E.g., Gentoo specifies explicitly in the wiki which options should be enabled for every software that requires something specific. For alpine I had to enable some options since otherwise, it had errors during the boot process (mostly related to missing /proc things, but not limited to).

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't officially support custom kernels. So there are no official recommendations.